# Content-Range header - allowed units?

Tags: api, http, rest

This is related to:
[How should I implement a COUNT verb in my RESTful web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393558/how-should-i-implement-a-count-verb-in-my-restful-web-service) , [Paging in a Rest Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924472/paging-in-a-rest-collection)
and [Using the HTTP Range Header with a range specifier other than bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434647/using-the-http-range-header-with-a-range-specifier-other-than-bytes)

Actually I think the -1 rated anwser here is correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434701/1237617

Generally anwsers say that you can use custom units citing the sec 3.12

```
  range-unit       = bytes-unit | other-range-unit
  bytes-unit       = "bytes"
  other-range-unit = token
```

However when you read the HTTP spec please notice the production rules are thus:

```
   Content-Range = "Content-Range" ":" content-range-spec
   content-range-spec      = byte-content-range-spec
   byte-content-range-spec = bytes-unit SP
                             byte-range-resp-spec "/"
                             ( instance-length | "*" )
```

The header spec only references bytes-unit from sec 3.12, not range-units, so I think that actually it's against the spec to use custom units here.

Am I missing something or is the popular anwser wrong?

EDIT: Since this probbably isn't clear, the gist of my question is:
rfc2616 sec14.16 only references bytes-unit. It never mentions range-unit, so range-unit production is not relevant for Content-Range, and thus only byte-units can be used.

I think this adresses my concerns best, although I needed some time to understand it (plus I wanted to make sure, that there is something wrong with the wording).

> This reflects the fact that, apparently, the first set of grammar rules has been specifically made for parsing and the second one for producing HTTP requests

thanks to elgaton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec, as being revised, allows custom range units. See [HTTPbis Part 5, Section 2](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-18.html#range.units).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I'm interedted in a solution for the current standard.

Comment: Jakub, what's the practical impact of the publication status of the new spec?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.
This spec is now a draft, and after (if) it's approved we can probbably expect practical adoption within a couple of years -- so?

While this is a useful quideline my motivation was to check if I understand the current specification correctly.

Comment: Jakub, you can use custom ranges right now if you control both client and server. (Note that Microsoft has done this for ages in Exchange)

Comment: Thanks again Julian
I'm also aware of the Dojo use in JsonRestStore - docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore#id7. However, while I understand it might be an ommision/error, can you confirm that literal reading of the current spec forbids it? Or explain to me what I'm reading wrong?

Comment: Jakub, literal reading of 2616 just shows that the spec is incomplete. That's why we are fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [HTTP/1.1 RFC, section 3.12](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.12), you will see that:

> The only range unit defined by HTTP/1.1 is "bytes". HTTP/1.1 implementations MAY ignore ranges specified using other units.

So, the `other-range-unit` token has been introduced only to make servers more "liberal" when accepting. This reflects the fact that, apparently, the first set of grammar rules has been specifically made for parsing and the second one for producing HTTP requests, so that servers could accept even invalid requests (they will be simply ignored) and clients would use only the universally-accepted `bytes` unit.

Therefore, I personally recommend to:

1. use only the `bytes` unit when acting as a client, and
2. accept other units (discarding the `Content-Range` header if they are invalid) when acting as a server.

Comment: I've seen that - but I think my point still holds:
the content-range production rules only reference byte-range.
I dont see how the range-unit production is relevant here - unless I can't read the spec properly?

Comment: The production is there only to remark the fact that servers should accept (and silently discard) even unknown units; in case the HTTP/1.1 specification is revised (that's the case, as @Julian Reschke pointed out) and a client supporting the new specs talks with a server supporting only the old one, the latter will be still able to parse and process the request without errors. (Remember that, in HTTP, the client sends the request immediately without checking first which protocol versions are supported by the server, so he has no means to know, unless a 505 error is returned).

Answer (score 1):

This is a purely personal opinion, but I think it is fairly consistent with how other HTTP extensions (custom methods or headers) are used. Here is how I read it: Yes I can use custom range units and no, I shouldn't submit a bug report when it gets ignored when passing through firewalls, web proxies, and other intermediaries. I conform to the HTTP spec when I'm sending it and they conform to HTTP when they ignore it. WebDAV uses HTTP extensions correctly, IMO, but rarely works over the Internet for exactly this reason. As I said, a personal opinion only.

Comment: This is an interesting point - I expect this will break caching. I mean that it will not onlt "not work" but it will cache and serve the partial content as full resource incorrectly if the header is ignored?

Comment: 13.4 says "However, a cache that does not support the Range and Content-Range headers MUST NOT cache 206 (Partial Content) responses", although I'm not sure if ignoring the header counts as "not supporting" for the puprose of this passage.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's OK to use custom units, because:

> This reflects the fact that, apparently, the first set of grammar
>   rules has been specifically made for parsing and the second one for
>   producing HTTP requests