# JavaScript Fetch download part of text file non-English character problem

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to download part of text file by fetch with range header property. But I get corrupted character from fetch.

Here part of my text file:

> Dalgalan sen de şafaklar gibi ey şanlı hilâl,
> Olsun artık dökülen kanlarımın hepsi helâl;
> Ebediyen sana yok, ırkıma yok izmihlâl:
> Hakkıdır, hür yaşamış bayrağımın hürriyet;
> Hakkıdır, Hakk’a tapan milletimin istiklâl!

and my javascript code is:

```
fetch("https://website.com/images/text.txt", {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
            'range': 'bytes=17-202'
        },
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.text();
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

The result is:

> �afaklar gibi ey şanlı hilâl;
> Olsun artık dökülen kanlarımın hepsi helâl.
> Ebediyen sana yok, ırkıma yok izmihlâl:
> Hakkıdır, hür yaşamış bayrağımın hürriyet;
> Hakkıd

As you can see the first character is unknown symbol, question mark, but it has to be **ş**.

I think non english charecters have 2 bytes so which are splited into. How can I solve this, thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480193/content-range-header-allowed-units

Answer (score 1):

The [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header doesn't affect the response from the fetch, it is used to tell the browser and the URL what you're sending. So it is meant to be used with `POST` requests. (But there is no harm using it here to).

The [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header is the exact opposite to the `Content-Type`, the `Accept` header should always be used when making a `GET` request, so you always know what kind of data to expect.

Although they have different use, their values are the same. So you should set your `Accept` header to the `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` value along with the other `headers` of your choice. Like so

```
fetch("https://website.com/images/text.txt").then(response => response.text()).then(...)
```

Comment: Okay... have you tried `fetching` the `file` without any options? Like in my edited answer

Comment: Without any of them?

Comment: Yes, when I run fetch with without headers, I download all file with no errors.

Comment: Yes I got the text, original text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229996/discussion-between-a-mola-and-dnaz).